# Having trouble specifying a schema name from MonetDB.R

Tags: r, monetdb

I am trying to connect to a table that is not in the sys schema. The code below works if sys.tablea exists.

```
conn <- dbConnect(dbDriver("MonetDB"), "monetdb://localhost/demo")
frame <- monet.frame(conn,"tablea")
```

If I define tablea in a different schema, e.g. xyz.tablea, then I get the error message

```
Server says 'SELECT: no such table 'tablea'' [#NA]
```

The account used to connect has rights to the table.

In a related question, is it possible to use camel-case from MonetDB.R? When I change the table name to TableA, the server again responds with

```
Server says 'SELECT: no such table 'tablea'' [#NA]
```

where the table name is all lower-case.

Comment: I've answered the second question about camel-case myself. Using escaped quotes works frame <- monet.frame(conn,"\"TableA\"")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using tables in other schemata is not possible with the current constructor of monet.frame. However, you can work around the issue as follows:

frame <- monet.frame(conn,"select * from xyz.tablea")

This trick also works with CamelCased table names.
For the next version, I am planning to fix the issue.

Comment: That worked! But I had to use the escaped quote trick to make the camel cased table names work

`a <- monet.frame(conn, "select * from xyz.\"TableA\"")`